# The HTML view inside my iOS app with WebView is empty

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, webview, native

I am trying to create a view with an `HTML` file, provided within the app, in the similar sample, but if I want to test it in `Testflight` it is empty :

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
```

**In the render:**

```
<WebView 
     useWebKit={true}
     source={ require('../../assets/platillo/platillo.html') } 
     originWhitelist={["*"]}
     style={‌{
          width: windowWidth,
          height: windowHeight,
          backgroundColor: "#ccc",
     }}
/>
```

**Can you help me, please?**